# Will Nginx run a Python FastAPI endpoint app?

Tags: python, nginx, fastapi

I don't see this answered directly, so it's confusing. None of the tutorials I can find are using Nginx. They use Uvicorn instead for their examples. I have a running Nginx server hosting my React website. I want to add some data science endpoints using Python to enhance the React website. Can I run the endpoints in Nginx?

Comment: If you use Nginx as a proxy, you can just have this as the single entry point forward traffic to you fastapi app running with uvicorn https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

Actually NO, Nginx listen to your fastAPI application through gunicorn. So, you need to run gunicorn and bind it `*.sock` file, then Nginx listen to it.

Or you may read from official uvicorn doc, then you can try yourself
https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/

Good Luck